# How can I replace eMule in Ubuntu?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source

I need an Ubuntu replacement for eMule (i.e. a software to download files from [eDonkey](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDonkey)). It must have the following requirements:

### Essential

- works in Ubuntu
- FOSS

### Much appreciated

Decreasing for importance:

1. Search function
2. Up to date (not an abandoned project)
3. GUI
4. Remote access from LAN

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Last release is more than four years old, so I classify it as an "abandoned project", but `aMule` still works. It is in the standard Ubuntu repos, so it can be installed with

```
$ sudo apt-get install amule
```